# How to hide BottomTabNavigator in certain screen in React Navigation (4.x)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-navigation

I need to hide the bottom tab navigator in my 'Chat' screen in my app built with React Native and React Navigation.
I have the following code:

```html
const UserNavigation= createStackNavigator({
  Profile:{screen:Profile},
  Search:{screen:Search},
  Feedback:{screen:Feedback},
  Chat: {screen:Chat}, //I need to hide the bottom tab navigation bar in this screen
},

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  User: UserNavigation, 
  Settings: SettingsNavigation,
 // etc...
});
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

You no need to hide the BottomNavBar, instead you can make the Chat Fragment into DialogFragment. So it covers the Full Screen

in Style.xml copy the following code

```
<style name="MY.DIALOG" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

extend your ChatFragment from Fragment to DialogFragment, then copy the following

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }
```

pass the instance of DialogFrament

```
loadDiaogFragment(new ChatFragment);
```

create the following function

```
private void loadDialogFragment(DialogFragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment.show(transaction, "Load Fragment");
}
```

to close the DialogFragment use following inside onClickLister

```
dismiss();
```